# Reload UITableView with New NSUserDefault Values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an array of dictionaries in NSUserDefaults and those values are used to display data in a table view in another tab on the tab bar. It works ok if I add a new value to my NSUserDefaults array and close the app then go back into it and go the table view tab. The problem I'm having is when I add a new object to the user defaults array then go to the table view tab without leaving the app. When I do this, the table view does not show the just added values.

Here is where I add the dictionaries to NSUserDefaults:

```
- (void)addFavorite {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *favoritesLoaded = [defaults objectForKey:@"favorites"];

    NSDictionary *fav = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         self.postTitle, @"title",
                         self.postUrlString, @"url",
                         nil];

    NSMutableArray *favorites = [NSMutableArray array];

    if (favoritesLoaded) {
        favorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:favoritesLoaded];
    } else {
        favorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    [favorites insertObject:fav atIndex:0];

    [defaults setObject:favorites forKey:@"favorites"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

In my table view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favorites"]) {
        self.redditPosts = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favorites"];
    }
    else {

    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    NSDictionary *post = [self.redditPosts objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    }
    if (cell) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [post objectForKey:@"title"];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: 1) `NSUserDefaults` is not  Data Model, don't use it that way. 2) You create a `NSMutableArray` and then immediately create a new one in the following `if/else` statement. You really need to understand why you write every line of code. 3) You are not reloading the tableView.

Answer (score 2):

just after inserting your new content you should reload the tableView:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

if this can take a while you can use the following so it won't freeze-up your app:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```